# How to set Symfony 2 slave database config in php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, configuration, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 2.7 application with Doctrine.

I am trying to setup slave databases.

We use lockerbox to manage our server configs.

We use Constants to keep all database configuration, ex:

```
<?php
define('DB_MASTER_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_MASTER_USER', 'user');
define('DB_MASTER_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_MASTER_NAME', 'db_name');

define('DB_SLAVE_ENABLED', FALSE);
define('DB_SLAVE_HOST', 'server-1,server-2');
define('DB_SLAVE_USER', 'username1,username2');
define('DB_SLAVE_PASS', 'password1,password2');
define('DB_SLAVE_NAME', 'db_name,db_name');
```

We can have multiple slave databases, the configs are comma-delimited.

Since the lockerbox config can change at any time and the lockerbox config is not editable to duplicate the Symfony YAML format I need a way to setup the configs with a parameters.php.

I am able to manually configure the slave database in the standard Symfony way:

```
...other configs...
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        keep_slave: true
        slaves:
            slave1:
                dbname: db_slave_name
                host: db_slave_server
                user: username
                password: password

...other configs
```

So far I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
<?php

// set default database connection info
$container->setParameter('database_host', DB_MASTER_HOST);
$container->setParameter('database_user', DB_MASTER_USER);
$container->setParameter('database_password', DB_MASTER_PASS);
$container->setParameter('database_name', DB_MASTER_NAME);

if (DB_SLAVE_ENABLED) {
    $slave_hosts = explode(',', DB_SLAVE_HOST);
    $slave_names = explode(',', DB_SLAVE_NAME);
    $slave_users = explode(',', DB_SLAVE_USER);
    $slave_passwords = explode(',', DB_SLAVE_PASS);

    $slave_count = min(count($slave_hosts), count($slave_names), count($slave_passwords), count($slave_users));

    if ($slave_count) {
        // add all slaves to config

        error_log('we have slaves and they are enabled');

        $container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.slaves.slave2.host', $slave_hosts[0]);
        $container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.slaves.slave2.name', $slave_names[0]);
        $container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.slaves.slave2.user', $slave_users[0]);
        $container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.slaves.slave2.password', $slave_passwords[0]);
    }

}   // end DB_SLAVE_ENABLED
```

Any ideas how to set multiple slave databases programmatically in Symfony 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your slaves config array in the `parameters.php` and just set the slaves parameter directly.

<kbd>parameters.php</kbd>

```
if (DB_SLAVE_ENABLED) {
    // ...
    if ($slave_count) {
        // add all slaves to config

        error_log('we have slaves and they are enabled');

        $slaves = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $slave_count; $i++) {
            $slaves['slave_'.$i] = array(
                'host'      => $slave_hosts[$i],
                'dbname'    => $slave_names[$i],
                'user'      => $slave_users[$i],
                'password'  => $slave_passwords[$i],

            );
        }

        $container->setParameter('database_slaves', $slaves);
    }
}
```

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
...other configs...
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        keep_slave: true
        slaves:   "%database_slaves%"

...other configs
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way! So obvious once the way is shown :-)